# Generate report in tabular form - JS

Tags: javascript, html, math, html-table

I would like to know how I can make the appearance in the form of a table, because the way I did it, for you to understand, it is all together in one line, but I need to leave it in a table, the code is simple, on one page html has a button "generate report" I click and generate the students' grades, but it needs to be in the form of a table, could they give this strength?

```
function report(){
    class Student {
        constructor(nr, _grade){
            this.gr = gr;
            this._grade = _grade;
    }

    get grade(){
        return this._grade;
    }
}

let students = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    let al = new Student(i,Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
    students.push(al);
}

function situation(grade) {
    return grade >= 60 ?'APPROVED' : 'DISAPPROVED'
}

document.write('Students grades')
let approvedies = 0;
for(let i = 0; i< students.length; i++) {
    document.write(`Student gr ${students[i].nr} - Grade ${students[i].grade} ${situation(students[i].grade)}`)
    if(sitution(students[i].grade) =='APPROVED'){
        approvedies++;
    }
}

document.write(`APPROVED ${Math.floor((approvedies/students.length)*100)}% | DISAPPROVED ${Math.floor(((students.length-approvedies)/students.length)*100)}%`)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `<table>` tag before the loop, `</table>` tag after the loop and inside the loop itself, in `document.write()` function, you could have it being written into`<tr> <td> content here </td> </tr>` tag.

Code :

```
document.write('Students grades')
document.write('<table border=1 >')
document.write('<tr><th>Your header content here</th></tr>')
let approvedies = 0;
for(let i = 0; i< students.length; i++) {
    document.write(`<tr><td>Student gr </td><td> ${students[i].nr}  </td><td>  Grade  </td><td> ${students[i].grade}  </td><td> ${situation(students[i].grade)}</td></tr>`)
    if(sitution(students[i].grade) =='APPROVED'){
        approvedies++;
    }
}
document.write('</table>')
document.write(`APPROVED ${Math.floor((approvedies/students.length)*100)}% | DISAPPROVED ${Math.floor(((students.length-approvedies)/students.length)*100)}%`)
```

Comment: document.write("<table border=1>");
 document.write('Notas dos alunos')
 let aprovados = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i< alunos.length; i++) {
  document.write(`<tr><th>Aluno nr ${alunos[i].nr}</th> <th>Nota ${alunos[i].nota} ${situacao(alunos[i].nota)}</th></tr>`)
  if(situacao(alunos[i].nota) =='APROVADO'){
   aprovados++;
  }
 }

 document.write(`<tr><td>APROVADO ${Math.floor((aprovados/alunos.length)*100)}% | REPROVADOS ${Math.floor(((alunos.length-aprovados)/alunos.length)*100)}%</td></tr>`)
    document.write("</table>");

Comment: I did it that way, is that what you wanted to go through?

Comment: I'd suggest you move the `document.write()` with `<th>` tag to before the loop, otherwise, since it is inside the `for` loop, it would be printed everytime. The remaining, seems to be fine.

Comment: Could you do that for me? because I did not understand, if I remove it from the loop, the table does not agree, at least the way I tried here.

Comment: i will edit my answer instead, the comments don't have a good formatiing